# changing array element not work in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wrote a simple code in python for doing a sorting manually because I needed my labels to change according to the numbers too. However, swapping the elements seems to be not working. Am I forgetting something fundamental?
Here is my code:

```
h = np.array(prediction)
h = h.transpose()
t = np.array(Z.columns.values)
for l in range(0, h.size-3):
    if h[0,l] < h[0, l+1]:
        g = h[0, l]
        h[0, l] = h[0, l+1]
        h[0, l+1] = g
        uu = t[l]
        t[l] = t[l+1]
        t[l+1] = uu
```

UPDATE 1:
Suppose that I have two arrays for demonstrating the number of cars in a parking and I want to sort it like to know which cars are more available in the parking. Both h and t are 1*N arrays. t holds the name of each car, for example, BMW', 'TOYOTA' and etc, and h holds the number of them for example 5,6 and etc. I want to sort the h array which is numbers and if an element has changed in the h, I want to change the name of relative cars in the other array too. It is a really simple thing for doing with other languages I know but because I am new in python I got into trouble. The interesting part is that code runs perfectly without error but the arrays don't change at all.

Comment: It is hard to understand what are you doing in the for loop, as the code does not look very idiomatic for Python. Can you provide a small sample input and desired output instead?

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting when trying to do this?

Comment: It looks like bubblesort.  Maybe just create an array to be sorted and run `.sort` on it?

Comment: btw in python you can swap in one atomic statement `a[0],a[1] = a[1],a[0]`

Comment: @Pykler, that one line version can fail with `np.arrays`.  They don't have the same copy on indexing rules as lists.

Comment: What's the shape of `t`?  Is the problem in swap `h` values or `t` values (rows?)?

Comment: Suppose that I have two arrays for demonstrating the number of cars in a parking and I want to sort it like to know which cars are more available in the parking. Both h and t are 1*N arrays. t holds the name of each car, for example, BMW', 'TOYOTA' and etc, and h holds the number of them for example 5,6 and etc. I want to sort the h array which is numbers and if an element has changed in the h, I want to change the name of relative cars in the other array too. It is a really simple thing for doing with other languages I know but because I am new in python I got into trouble.

Comment: The code runs without error but arrays don't change at all.

Comment: I don't want a word description of your arrays.  I want to see a couple of arrays that I can plug into your code (without much thinking), and observe what is happening step by step.  Better yet, you could do that detailed kind of observation, and report back the findings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your requirements, but at a glance, there are a bunch of assignments happening within that `if`, and none outside of it. If your arrays aren't changing my guess is that the code inside the if isn't executing, either because the test in the `if` is failing, or because `range(0, h.size-3)` is empty.

Stick some `print`s in there and see if that code is actually running!

Comment: I did use some print command and seems that the code goes through if statement. But Here For better clarity, I removed the print command.

Comment: How are you determining that the arrays don't change? It seems pretty clear that if the body of the if runs, they will change. Maybe try printing out h three times in the if, once after each of the first three lines, and then compare those results to the final result?